# How to check whether a number is repeated in a matrix using C language?

Tags: c

I wrote the below code to check whether any numbers of the multiple dimensional array a[5][5] are repeated or not.
This is the output that I got using this code.[The Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BP53B.png). Some numbers are missing and 45 is repeated 6 times. What's the problem with my code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
     int main()
     {
       int a[5][5]={{14,10,87,45,17},{90,46,48,49,41},{42,62,45,36,38},{56,45,53,59,38},{62,64,77,83,90}};
       int i,j,x,y;
     
      for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        for(j=0;j<5;j++){
           for(x=0;x<5;x++){
             for(y=0;y<5;y++){
              if((a[i][j]==a[x][y])&&(i!=x)&&(j!=y)){
                  printf("%d ",a[i][j]);
              }
            }
        }}}
      
     return 0;
     }
```

Comment: Copy the matrix, convert the copy to a linear array, and sort it. Then it'll be easy to detect all the repeated values with a single pass through the array.

Comment: In `a[i][j]==a[x][y])&&(i!=x)&&(j!=y)`, you do not want `(i!=x)&&(j!=y)` but `(i!=x || j!=y)`. Aside from that, your post does not ask a question. Edit it to ask a specific question and to provide a [mre]. Include the observed output and the desired output.

Comment: @Caleb: That's a good idea in principle, but in practice multiple dimensional arrays are already linear arrays under the hood anyway.  You can treat them like a linear array by doing a simple math conversion, without the need for copying or translation.

Comment: @RobertHarvey The conversion could just be a type cast -- the point is just to treat it as a 1xn^2 array instead of an nxn. But you obviously need to copy it before sorting if the array is needed for anything else (and it's hard to think of a reason to care whether there are any dupes if you're not using it for something else).

Comment: @RobertHarvey Could you please explain how can I treat it as a linear array?

Comment: C uses pointer arithmetic to get at the individual elements of an array.  Just emulate that math yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can start x and y to i+1 and j respectively:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int a[5][5]={{14,10,87,45,17},{90,46,48,49,41},{42,62,45,36,38},{56,45,53,59,38},{62,64,77,83,90}};
  int i,j,rowsum,columnsum,number,x,y;

  for(i=0;i<5;i++){
    for(j=0;j<5;j++){
      printf("%d  ",a[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }

  printf("\n\n");
   for(i=0;i<5;i++){
      for(j=0;j<5;j++){
        for(x=i+1;x<5;x++){
          for(y=j;y<5;y++){
          if(a[i][j]==a[x][y]){
              printf("%d ",a[i][j]);
          }
        }
     }}}

    return 0;
}
```

NB: This is not the optimized way to do it.